# Do a while loop with switch statement

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve the same result as the code below but using the switch statement instead of all those if? Thank you!

```js
var a = 1;
while(a < 10){
 if(a <= 5) { console.log(a); }
 if(a > 5 && a < 8) { console.info(a); }
 if(a >= 8) { console.warn(a); }
 a++;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Why add the switch, it'll only serve to clutter up your code. As it stands it's very readable and clean.

Comment: I was putting the variable a as parameter for switch, instead of true as Rahul did, so that is why it didn't work. "Thanks" for negative points... lame help from those who give negatives to a beginner. That is how you encourage people here?!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var a = 1;
while(a < 10){
    switch (true) {
        case (a <= 5):
            console.log(a);
            break;
        case (a > 5 && a < 8):
            console.info(a);
            break;
        case (a >= 8):
            console.warn(a);
            break;
    }
  a++;
}
```

*On a personal note using **if** would be better as it makes your code look much cleaner and compact than using **switch..case***

Comment: you can omit `(a > 5 && ...):`, and the parenthesis as well.